# Unable to boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-10

I've recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS dual boot with Windows 10 and I still can’t get access back to Windows 10. When grub appears after switch on my computer it gives me a few options apart from Ubuntu, like Windows UEFI boot and some more.
[image: GRUB menu screenshot]

I've tried with all of them, when I click some it says that it couldn't find the file, and some others take me through the reparation menu of windows to end up in Ubuntu's GRUB again. 
I've been through some of the posts on this topic, and I've already tried a few things.

1. Reinstall and refresh grub via Boot-Repair.
2. I've also tried as recommended in another post to create the file `/boot/grub/custom.cfg`.
3. I've also run boot info script so you can have some more information about this.
4. I do have the Bootinfo that I got after running Boot-Repair app. 
   This is the URL I got after running the Boot-Repair:
   http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hrFf6Ssh8f/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) This is how you should install in UEFI mode.

Comment: Are both Win and Ubuntu on the same drive, or separate? I've solved this issue previously by disconnecting my Ubuntu drive. Then connecting it again and updating grub after getting windows working.

Comment: and are you using a live USB for Boot Repair, or are you running it off your Ubuntu install disk?

Comment: Boot-Repair report also gives a pastebin site link. Just post the link, so we can see your exact configuration.

Comment: And I did use a flashe USB to install UBUNTU. And I put bot in differents drives.

Comment: @Melebius i Ve already update the post with more info about it.